# Gtkmm 3.0 Entry get_text always returns the same initial text

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtk2

I am having a strange problem with Gtkmm entries in C++.
I defined a Gtk::Entry here called inputEntry. I have a function called csf.

Where I declare the entry in main:

```
// Create input entry
Gtk::Entry inputEntry;
inputEntry.set_editable(TRUE);
inputEntry.set_text("3.55");
inputEntry.signal_activate().connect(sigc::bind<float>(sigc::ptr_fun(&csf), atof(inputEntry.get_text().c_str())));
```

I later attach this entry to a grid, then add that grid to the main window, then show all the widgets on the grid, then the grid itself.

Where I declare CSF (there is a prototype at the beginning of the code):

```
void csf(float sa)
{
    printf("%f \n", sa);
}
```

However, strangely, when I run the program, no matter what I type into the Gtk::Entry, the terminal always shows 3.55 when I submit. I tried changing the set_text to "1.11", and it always showed 1.11 when I submitted. I even tried putting a second set_text to "1.11", and it would always show 1.11, then, I tried with no set_text at all, and it would always show 0. The value of the entry, regardless of what I type in, be it 300000 or 0.1, always show print the initial value and only the initial value of the Gtk::Entry. What is wrong?

Note: I have done this in Python before, pretty much the same way, and it worked. I want to try doing it in C++. Maybe it is because I didn't implement something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's C++ question, not a gtk one.

In line:

```
inputEntry.signal_activate().connect(sigc::bind<float>(sigc::ptr_fun(&csf), atof(inputEntry.get_text().c_str())));
```

You are calling function `csf` with a double created from string "3.55". In order to get what you want:

```
inputEntry.signal_activate().connect(sigc::bind<Gtk::Entry*>(sigc::ptr_fun(&csf), &inputEntry));
```

(...)

```
void csf(Gtk::Entry* entry)
{
  std::cout<<atof(entry.get_text().c_str())<<" "<<std::endl;
}
```

Change of entry's text to double must occur after the activation. In your solution it was at signal connection.